# Скрыть в трей программу tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Мне нужен код, который сворачивал программу в tray по нажатии на кнопку, и открывал программу при нажатии на иконку программы этой же программы в трее.

Comment: возможно вам поможет https://python-scripts.com/minimizing-to-system-tray-wxpython

Comment: Посмотрите пример тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54835399/running-a-tkinter-window-and-pystray-icon-together

Answer (score 1):

**Tkinter — изначально не лучшее решение для работы с треем**. Есть намного лучше библиотеки, как тот же PyQt5, который стандартными методами библиотеки способен дать функционал для работы с треем. Для работы с функционалом трея придётся использовать дополнительные библиотеки, такие как PyWin и pystray.

Для своей работы трей использует ивент-цикл, что и tkinter, а значит потребуется добавить асинхронность, для работы обоих вместе, а это лишь излишнее усложнение процесса. Намного рациональнее будет изначально использовать хорошую библиотеку, где "прямо с пакета" есть функционал для работы с треее.

Поддержку трея можно сделать лишь через костыли в виде других библиотек, так как стандартный Tkinter не поддерживает трей. В реальных проектах, в которых нужен будет подобный функционал, зачастую используют более высокоуровневые библиотеки и с большим функционалом, как например PyQT.

*Этот вопрос повторяет вопрос с англоязычного стека: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54399137/hide-tkinter-window-in-system-tray*